# Google Plus Text Share Button

Tags: html, google-plus

I am trying to create a simple google plus post page that take text from text box and when click on google sharing button text will be posted automatically. Here is my code I am using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML Forms</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form>
  <div>
    <label for="example">Let's submit some text</label>
    <input id="example" type="text" name="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <g:plus action="share"></g:plus>

    <script >
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'zh-CN',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
  </div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Its a simple html page. I use form submit option. I am beginner, so I am not exactly getting why it did not take text from text box.

Answer (score 0):

The only configurable content attribute for the [Google+ share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) is `data-href` and it goes directly on `<g:plus action="share" data-href="https:/example.com"></g:plus>`. The only other configuration the share button supports is for how it will be displayed.

The Google+ share button only supports sharing URLs and does not support sharing text.

You could try using [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) but they require a lot more setup and a call to action.

Comment: can you please create a setup and call to action code?

Comment: The included interactive posts link has a step by step guide.